# Pointer to arrays syntax

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have a question about syntax of pointer to arrays.
Well we know arrays are pointers themselves(what our uni professor said) so why when we point to them with another pointer (which would be a pointer to pointer) we use this syntax:

```
int array[10]; 
int *pointer = array;
```

Instead of this syntax:

```
int array[10];
int **pointer = &array;
```

Although i know this would be correct using malloc but why not in the normal way, is it a compiler or syntax thing or i am wrong somewhere else??

Comment: Array-to-pointer is a **conversion**. Saying arrays are pointers makes as much sense as saying `double`s are `int`s because you can go `int x = 5.5;` . In fact it is a lossy conversion just like double->int, because you lose the length of the array.

Comment: _"Well we know arrays are pointers themselves"_ No no no no no no no no **no**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well we know arrays are pointers themselves

No.  Arrays are not pointers.  Arrays are arrays.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or the unary `&` operator, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to`T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  However, no storage is set aside for a pointer in addition to the array elements themselves.

So, given the declaration

```
int array[10];
```

the type of the expression `array` is "10-element array of `int`"; unless `array` is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it will decay to type `int *`.  So

```
int *ptr = array;
```

works.

The type of `&array` is *not* `int **`; the type is `int (*)[10]`, or "pointer to 10-element array of `int`".  You'd declare and initialize such a pointer as

```
int (*ptr)[10] = &array;
```

Answer (score 5):

Tell your professor they are wrong. Arrays are **not** pointers. Arrays can [**decay**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to pointers, but they **are** not pointers.

`int* pointer = array;` declares a pointer that points to the first element in `array`.

`int** pointer = &array;` is not correct. As mentioned by [jschultz410](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564515/jschultz410) in the comments, the type of `&array` is *not* `int**`, it is `int (*)[10]` aka a pointer to an array of 10 ints, which cannot decay to `int**`.

Comment: Because the type of &array is actually int (*)[10].  In C++ you need a cast.  In C, you can probably skate by with a warning.

Comment: Also, it's not actually pointing to a pointer pointing to the first element in array.  It is still pointing at the first element of array, it just requires two dereferences to get an int out of it.

Comment: *Your assumption that "arrays are pointers themselves" is not entirely correct.* It is in fact entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

First of all this definition of a pointer

```
int array[10]; 
int **pointer = &array;
```

is invalid. In the right side of the declaration there is an expression having type `int ( * )[10]` while in the left side there is identifier of type `int **`. There is no implicit conversion between pointers `int ( * )[10]` and `int **` . So the compiler shall issue a diagnostic message.

The correct definition will look

```
int array[10]; 
int ( *pointer )[10] = &array;
```

Now we can consider what is the difference between these two definitions

```
int array[10]; 
int *pointer = array;
```

and

```
int array[10]; 
int ( *pointer )[10] = &array;
```

In the first case the size of the object pointed to by pointer `pointer` is equal to `sizeof( int )`. So if to use the pointer arithmetic then after evaluation of expression `++pointer` the value in the pointer will be increased by `sizeof( int )` bytes. If for example `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the value in the pointer will be increased by `4`.

In the second case the size of the object pointed to by pointer `pointer` is equal to `10 * sizeof( int )` that is if `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4 then the size of the object is equal to `40`. So if the pointer will be increased `++pointer` its value will be increased by `40`.

Also dereferencing the pointer in the first case will give you an object of type `int` while dereferencing the pointer in the second case will give you an object of type `int[10]` that is an array.

And arrays are not pointers. Simply they are usually converted to pointers to their first elements in expressions. From the C Standard

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

If you write for example

```
int array[10]; 
int *pointer = array;
```

then `sizeof( array )` is not equal to `sizeof( pointer )` though you can use the common syntax to access elements of the array:

`array[ i ]` and `pointer[ i ]` and will get the same result..